# Why Redux, why not useContext + useReducer for beginner?

Tags: react-redux

Which is better to start with useContext+useReducer Or Redux itself and what are the cons of using each?

Answer (score 1):

They are not mutually exclusive, and the general answer might be that it depends on the project you are working on.

**useContext** & **useReducer** are part of React and are not so much opinionated on how you should use them in your implementations.

**Redux** is an extra dependency and is very opinionated about how to do things - that might be good if your app has lots of data and you need some structure to keep track of its flow.

You should definitively try both and make yourself an opinion.