# Difference between useContext, useReducer and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-context

I am learning about Redux, but one question that is confusing me that is why I have to use Redux instead of `useContext` and `useReducer`? That's why I am curious about the differences between `useContext`, `useReducer`, and `Redux`?

Answer (score 1):

They are not mutually exclusive, and the general answer might be that it depends on the project you are working on.

**useContext** & **useReducer** are part of React and are not so much opinionated on how you should use them in your implementations.

**Redux** is an extra dependency and is very opinionated about how to do things - that might be good if your app has lots of data and you need some structure to keep track of its flow. [*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58366088/1952287)

Also reference:

- [Use UseReduce and useContext with redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69157432/use-usereduce-and-usecontext-with-redux)
- [migrating from useContext + useReducer to Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372933/migrating-from-usecontext-usereducer-to-redux)